# How to summarize leave to without public holidays?

Tags: mysql, datetime, summarize, holidays-gem

Hi all (before holidays).

In this case I have added new leave in this table:

```
+--------+---------+---------+-------------+----------+--------------------------
|ID_LEAVE|ID_WORKER| FNAME   | LNAME | BEGIN_DATE         | END_DATE            | 
+--------+---------+---------+---------+-------------+--------------------+------
| 8      |   10    | MARIO   | NEED  |2019-04-22 07:00:00 |2019-04-23 15:00:00  | 
+--------+---------+---------+-------------+----------+--------------------------
```

But I know the holidays are representing like this:

[image]

What I have done yet?

I have done that query which summarize leave time of all employees grouped by `ID_LEAVE`

```
SELECT leave.ID_LEAVE, leave.ID_WORKER, workers.FNAME, workers.LNAME, leave.BEGIN_DATE, leave.END_DATE,  
FROM 
(SELECT ADDDATE('1970-01-01', t4 * 10000 + t3 * 1000 + t2 * 100 + t1 * 10 + t0) AS date_value 
 FROM 
(SELECT 0 t0 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t0, 
 (SELECT 0 t1 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t1, 
 (SELECT 0 t2 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t2, 
 (SELECT 0 t3 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t3, 
 (SELECT 0 t4 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t4) calendar 
INNER JOIN leave ON calendar.date_value BETWEEN DATE(leave.BEGIN_DATE) AND DATE(leave.END_DATE) 
INNER JOIN workers ON leave.ID_WORKER = workers.ID_WORKER 
WHERE NOT WEEKDAY(date_value) IN (5, 6)
GROUP BY ID_LEAVE;
```

Now I'd like that query which summarize leave time of all employees but **without holidays which I represented in above picture.** What should I do? Should I create new "holidays" table and then download that date from this table or add dates in above query?

Comment: For starters, you should create a new _calendar_ table which contains the official leave dates.  Once you have that, any query you have in mind would be relatively straightforward.

Comment: This would be a lot easier if you are prepared to add an actual table with one row per day, and have something on that row to mark whether the day is a public holiday etc. Are you prepared to do this?

Comment: I think adding new calendar table would be easier, but how consider that days in query after adding "holidays" table?

Comment: A separate table for all dates is not necessary, at least not in MySQL 8.0 (given that it now supports [recursive CTEs](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/224182/generate-dates-between-date-ranges-in-mysql)). Thus - OP, which MySQL version?

Comment: @amadan true, but it makes things a lot easier and most pro DBAs I've worked with have advocated using one- they take up minimal storage space, are easy to compute as a one time op and This can be more optimal than generating data on the fly every time a query is run

Comment: @Amadan i have 10.1.37-MariaDB

Comment: @CaiusJard: I am not convinced without a benchmark, and even then I wouldn't bother unless it was a bottleneck. PostgreSQL [`generate_series`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-srf.html) is super handy, as is MariaDB's [virtual sequence tables](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/sequence-storage-engine/).

Comment: Hi @Prochu1991 . If I'm not mistaken, this is something like a Time attendance software you're trying to make, correct? And you're concern about how to update the holidays once you've created a calendar table is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after analysing all comments and answer i've found that solution:

1) I created holidays table.

2) I've created that query which selects all and summarize leave_time without weekends and holidays:

```
SELECT *, 
TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(TIME(leave.END_DATE), TIME(leave.BEGIN_DATE))))), '%H:%i:%s') AS 'LEAVE TIME' 
FROM 
(SELECT ADDDATE('1970-01-01', t4 * 10000 + t3 * 1000 + t2 * 100 + t1 * 10 + t0) AS date_value FROM 
(SELECT 0 t0 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t0, 
(SELECT 0 t1 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t1, 
(SELECT 0 t2 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t2, 
(SELECT 0 t3 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t3, 
(SELECT 0 t4 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t4) calendar 
INNER JOIN `leave` ON calendar.date_value BETWEEN DATE(leave.BEGIN_DATE) AND DATE(leave.END_DATE) 
WHERE NOT WEEKDAY(date_value) IN (5, 6) AND NOT DATE(date_value) IN (SELECT DATE_HOLIDAY FROM holidays) GROUP BY ID_LEAVE;
```

I've just tested in below links:

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=a25a3dc5762dba08541c002f12efc024

Has someone any warnings on it? 
Thx a lot and have a nice easter ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a calendar table that lists all the days (not just holidays, but every day of the year for the next X years, and a column for whether the day is a public holiday etc) then your query looks like

```
SELECT l.id_leave, count(*)
FROM calendar c INNER JOIN leave l ON c.calendar_date BETWEEN l.start_date AND l.end_date
WHERE c.day_type NOT IN ('publicholiday', 'weekend')
GROUP BY l.id_leave
```

There's a lot more complexity you can add but this is the core. Not sure why your leaves start at 7am and finish at 10pm, but you might want to add some logic if you're allowing fractional days off - extend the start date back to midnight (so the between works properly) then use a case when to build in the fraction depending on if the date being considered is a start or end date or interim date

Comment: This is a pretty terrible idea. You don't need it. Just an entry for every day that's a holiday, and a join.

Comment: Feel free to submit your own answer rather than being nothing but a critic of others. SO is all about being helpful to the people who ask questions; attacking people who post answers with unjustified claims such as "this is a terrible idea" is helpful to no one

Comment: i thought that about inner join 'holidays' table but on the other hand what about `ON calendar.date_value`?

Comment: Your holidays table only contains holidays. You still need something to expand your date range out into N Rows so you can count them. I'm advocating having your "one row per day" calendar table do that (you've used a large number of unions to achieve the same but it's made your query a bit harder to read and maintain

Answer (score 0):

Variant without a full calendar table, but with a holiday table as in the question (though with full dates - you'd have to populate it for each year):

```
SELECT L.id_leave, COUNT(*)
FROM (
    SELECT '1970-01-01' + INTERVAL (seq) DAY AS date
    FROM seq_0_to_24836
) C
INNER JOIN leaves L
    ON C.date BETWEEN L.begin_date AND L.end_date
    AND NOT WEEKDAY(date_value) IN (5, 6)
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM holidays H WHERE H.date = C.date
    )
GROUP BY L.id_leave
```

Note: seq_0_to_24836 is MariaDB-only extension, and will here generate all dates from epoch till end of 2037.